Inquiry about a real image or a 3D image of an engineering device
I am a researcher in applied mathematics.
I am studying a diagram of an engineering device "Summer air-conditioner for hot and dry weather" and looking for real pictures of it or a three-dimensional diagram.
It is represented by the following diagram.


Air conditioner is  consists of seven components as follows: (1) two air dampers (2) two air filters  (3) cooling coils  (4) an adiabatic humidifier, and (5) a water eliminator.
The question is: Are there real pictures or three-dimensional diagrams available for above diagrams?
I found a lot of pictures but I have no experience with the engineering terms...does it work on the same principle as in the diagram?... Like this


In particular, I am looking for a diagram of real devices that work on this principle (three-dimensional or a real image)
Please help

There are many pictures on the web of the real parts of air conditioning systems. Google should be quite productive.

@SolarMike I found a lot of pictures but I have no experience with the engineering terms...does it work on the same principle as in the diagram?... Like  this link

Do some research for "latent heat of vaporisation" and "latent heat of condensation".

parts of top picture is same as A and F in bottom picture

Your upper diagrams are just a partial air conditioner and a whole humidifier in series. The missing parts of the air conditioner are what connect to the cooling coil (aka evaporator)- the condenser/compressor assembly.
